# Indexing unnamed QJsonDocument in Qt < 5.10

Tags: qt, qjson, qjsondocument

Given unnamed JSON document:

```
[
    {
    },
    {
    },
 ]
```

Qt 5.10+ has `operator[]` for QJsonDocument, so we can address any of them by index:

```
json_doc[1];
```

How does one do the same in older versions of Qt?

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example the Json document is represented by a Json array. You might get it like:

```
if (document.isArray() {
    auto a = document.array();
    // TODO: check the array size before
    auto v = a[0];
}
```